# Use an imported object (from the servlet) inside a script tag

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets

My servlet sends to the JSP page an object. This object has some attributes and depending on these attributes i want to change the color during a hover action. One solution is to change the hover style directly in my JSP page. But i was wondering, can i use somehow this object inside the script tag and take the decisions from there? I found [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) but it didn't work (or i use it a wrong way)!

```
   <script>    
      $(document).ready(function() {
        //import myObject;

      });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSP gets **rendered on the server** and sent to the client. **The client (browser) does not know anything about your Java/JSP code**.

But, you can render properties of your Java object into the rendered page, like:

```
<script>
    var stringVariable = "${myObject.myStringProperty}";
    var intVariable = ${myObject.myIntProperty};
</script>
```

This will be rendered on your server, and the browser will see it like:

```
<script>
    var stringVariable = "Hello World!";
    var intVariable = 4711;
</script>
```

Using this technique, you can use your server side variables on the client, wherever you need them (HTML, CSS, Javascript).

Comment: thx @Uooo! Since i import my object, how can i use some methods of getters that i have in myObject.class to get the values i want? Can i do this?

Comment: @yaylitzis Yes, in this example their names would be `getMyStringProperty()` and `getMyIntProperty()`. Read about [Expression language](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info) for more information.